# jquery referencing multiple elements in one line

Tags: jquery, element

How can i write this in one line.

```
$('#id').whatever();
$('#id1').whatever();
$('.class').whatever();
```

Comment: **CSV** Comma Separated Values `$('#id, #id1, .class')`

Comment: @RobertPitt - Those aren't comma separated values; they're comma separated selectors.  **CSV** is a data format.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As with CSS, you can use commas to join together multiple distinct selectors:

```
$('#id, #id1, .class').whatever();
```

Comment: I thought $("#id','#id1') is equivalent to $('#id1').find('#id'). Is this not right.

Comment: @alex, you're right, but in @Phrogz's answer the comma is *inside* the quotes.