# How to reference multiple selector variables in one line with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I just read through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4703325/3465372) SO question as well as some others that are similar to mine.  However, I'd like to know if it is possible to mash together several selectors that are already captured in variables.

```
var id1 = $('#id1'),
    id2 = $('#id2'),
    class1 = $('.class');
```

I'm looking for this functionality...

```
id1.whatever();
id2.whatever();
class1.whatever();
```

... but in a single line, if possible.  I've tried this and it does not work:

```
(id1, id2, class1).whatever();
```

Is there a more concise way to do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18504075/how-to-use-multiple-jquery-object-variables-as-selectors

Comment: `combinedSelector = [id1.selector, id2.selector, class1.selector].join(', ');`

Comment: Sure enough.  This is a duplicate.  I searched about a dozen SO questions before posting.  I guess that because I did not know the `add()` method, it did not come up in my search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
id1.add(id2).add(class1).whatever();
```

Comment: think you wanted `add()`

Comment: Never heard of `and`, also why start with an empty jquery object? Why not `id1.add().add()....`

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon Because this would change `id1`.

Comment: No it does not : http://jsfiddle.net/Qkn7e/. It is the same as using filter, it does not change the original object.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon You're right.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [add()](http://api.jquery.com/add):

```
ad1.add(id2).add(class1).whatever();
```

---

But I strongly recommend to use a common class and then apply your method on that class.

Comment: Definitely agree with consolidating into a common class where possible.